# glib build failure after adding Y2038 glibc patches

Tags: glibc

I am facing one issue with IMX7 Yocto build failure, we have added the Y2038 issue fix patches
in glibc, after this when we build using bitbake we are getting build error in other module, however glibc has no failure.

> ./.libs/g-ir-compiler:
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-jupiter-linux-gnueabi/gobject-introspection/1.48.0-r0/build/.libs/libgirepository-1.0.so.1:
>   no version information available (required by
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/imx7dsabresd-jupiter//usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0) ./.libs/g-ir-compiler:
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-jupiter-linux-gnueabi/gobject-introspection/1.48.0-r0/build/.libs/libgirepository-1.0.so.1:
>   no version information available (required by
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/imx7dsabresd-jupiter//usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0) ./.libs/g-ir-compiler: symbol lookup error:
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/imx7dsabresd-jupiter//usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0:
>   undefined symbol: pcre_free ./.libs/g-ir-compiler: symbol lookup
>   error:
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/imx7dsabresd-jupiter//usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0:
>   undefined symbol: pcre_free ./.libs/g-ir-compiler: symbol lookup
>   error:
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/imx7dsabresd-jupiter//usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0:
>   undefined symbol: pcre_free ./.libs/g-ir-compiler: symbol lookup
>   error:
>   /data/server/tmp/fsl-community-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/imx7dsabresd-jupiter//usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0:
>   undefined symbol: pcre_free If the above error message is about
>   missing .so libraries, then setting up GIR_EXTRA_LIBS_PATH in the
>   recipe should help. (typically like this:
>   GIR_EXTRA_LIBS_PATH="${B}/something/.libs" ) make[2]: ***
>   [gir/libxml2-2.0.typelib] Error 1

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think backporting these two patches to core might be helpful

[glib-2.0](http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/?id=365f4092070b2e7978b8db65298308f4e770a501)

[libpcre](http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/commit/?id=839eebceecf33d106592bab154481486533ece75)

Comment: Hi Khem, Thanks for your response, we have both patches already in place.
If we don't add gobject-introspection patch, then there is no build failure. this build failure occurs only when we add one patch in glibc for changing the time api's to use 64 bit time api's 
Without above modification build is ok, in glibc we replace time related variable to use 64 bit variables, glibc build is success but only when it try to build gobject-introspection then it fails, without gobject-introspection build is ok. Please provide some pointers to debug and fix this build issue.

Comment: -- a/bits/stat.h
+++ b/bits/stat.h
@@ -48,10 +48,17 @@ struct stat
 #else
     __off64_t st_size;         /* Size of file, in bytes.  */
 #endif
-
+#ifdef Y2038
     __time_t st_atime;         /* Time of last access.  */
     __time_t st_mtime;         /* Time of last modification.  */
     __time_t st_ctime;         /* Time of last status change.  */
+#else
+    __time64_t st_atime;               /* Time of last access.  */
+    __time64_t st_mtime;               /* Time of last modification.  */
+    __time64_t st_ctime;               /* Time of last status change.  */
+#endif

Comment: +++ b/bits/time.h +#ifdef Y2038
 struct timeval
   {
     __time_t tv_sec;           /* Seconds.  */
     __suseconds_t tv_usec;     /* Microseconds.  */
   };
+#else
+struct timeval
+{
+  __time64_t tv_sec;            /* Seconds.  */
+  __int64_t tv_usec;           /* Microseconds.  */
+};
+#endif

Comment: +++ b/bits/types.h
@@ -137,6 +137,9 @@ __STD_TYPE __RLIM_T_TYPE __rlim_t;  /* Type for resource measurement.  */
 __STD_TYPE __RLIM64_T_TYPE __rlim64_t; /* Type for resource measurement (LFS).  */
 __STD_TYPE __ID_T_TYPE __id_t;         /* General type for IDs.  */
 __STD_TYPE __TIME_T_TYPE __time_t;     /* Seconds since the Epoch.  */
+
+__STD_TYPE __TIME64_T_TYPE __time64_t;  /* Seconds since the Epoch, Y2038-safe.  */

Comment: +++ b/bits/typesizes.h
@@ -61,6 +61,8 @@
 #define __SYSCALL_ULONG_TYPE   __ULONGWORD_TYPE
 #define __CPU_MASK_TYPE        __ULONGWORD_TYPE

+#define __TIME64_T_TYPE         __SQUAD_TYPE
+

Comment: +++ b/time/difftime.c
@@ -29,7 +29,7 @@

 /* Return the difference between TIME1 and TIME0, where TIME0 <= TIME1.
    time_t is known to be an integer type.  */
-
+#if 0
 static double
 subtract (time_t time1, time_t time0)
 {
@@ -96,14 +96,21 @@ subtract (time_t time1, time_t time0)
       return delta;
     }
 }
-
+#endif
+double
+__difftime64 (time_t time1, time_t time0)
+{
+  /* Subtract the smaller integer from the larger, convert the difference to
+     double, and then negate if needed.  */
+  return time1 < time0 ? - (time0 - time1) : (time1 - time0);
+}

Comment: +#ifdef Y2038
   if (TYPE_BITS (time_t) <= DBL_MANT_DIG
       || (TYPE_FLOATING (time_t) && sizeof (time_t) < sizeof (long double)))
     return (double) time1 - (double) time0;
@@ -117,5 +124,8 @@ __difftime (time_t time1, time_t time0)
      double, and then negate if needed.  */

   return time1 < time0 ? - subtract (time0, time1) : subtract (time1, time0);
+#else
+  return time1 < time0 ? - (time0 - time1) : (time1 - time0);
+#endif

Comment: +++ b/time/time.h
@@ -71,8 +71,11 @@ __USING_NAMESPACE_STD(clock_t)
 # include <bits/types.h>

 __BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD
+#ifdef Y2038
 /* Returned by `time'.  */
 typedef __time_t time_t;
+#endif
+typedef __time64_t time_t;

Comment: +#ifdef Y2038
 struct timespec
   {
     __time_t tv_sec;           /* Seconds.  */
     __syscall_slong_t tv_nsec; /* Nanoseconds.  */
   };
-
+#else
+struct timespec
+{
+  __time64_t tv_sec;            /* Seconds.  */
+  __syscall_slong_t tv_nsec;    /* Nanoseconds.  */
+  int: 32;                      /* Hidden padding */
+};
+#endif

Comment: +++ b/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/bits/time.h
@@ -27,11 +27,19 @@

 /* A time value that is accurate to the nearest
    microsecond but also has a range of years.  */
+#ifdef Y2038
 struct timeval
   {
     __time_t tv_sec;           /* Seconds.  */
     __suseconds_t tv_usec;     /* Microseconds.  */
   };
+#else
+struct timeval
+{
+  __time64_t tv_sec;            /* Seconds.  */
+  __int64_t tv_usec;           /* Microseconds.  */
+};
+#endif

Comment: Hi Khem, Above changes i am doing in glibc package, posted in different comments as one comment it can not come. With this everthing is fine untill we build gobject-introspection package, once we add this package then we see the build error, please suggest

Comment: you need GLib-2.52.3+ whats the version in use ?

Comment: Hi Khem,I upgraded to GLib-2.54.3 using glib-2.0_2.54.3.bb, but still i get the same error